# Checking boxes using Xpath w/ Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am creating a .py script to automate queries to the [World Bank data repository](https://databank.worldbank.org/source/education-statistics) using Selenium.

The script will check boxes from the "Countries", "Series", and "Time" menus. I don't have problems selecting arrays of countries.

```
country_codes = ['AUT', 'BRA', etc.]
for country in country_codes:
    country_xpath = '//*[@id="chk[Stat_Ctry_Ext].[List].&[' + str(country) + ']"]'
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(country_xpath).click()
```

However, selecting series raises a `NoSuchElementException` error.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="chk[STATS_Series_Ext].[Topic].&[UIS.NERA.2.M]"]')
```

[Image: Web Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZhYG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code and let me know if you face any issue -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get('https://databank.worldbank.org/source/education-statistics')
time.sleep(5)

country_codes = ['AFG', 'AUT', 'BRA']

for country in country_codes:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="chk[Stat_Ctry_Ext].[List].&[' + country + ']"]').click()

# Click on the series tab
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//a[contains(@title,"Series")])[1]').click()

Series_UIS_NERA_2_M = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="chk[STATS_Series_Ext].[Topic].&[UIS.NERA.2.M]"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="chk[STATS_Series_Ext].[Topic].&[UIS.NERA.2.M]"]').click()
```

Comment: If it does then it would be nice if you can mark it as an answer. So that people will understand that this issue has been addressed.

Comment: A couple of questions: is the fact that presence_of_element_located() also works here purely because my connection is fast enough that the the menu is already visible before the timeout elapses? Also: is it a good practice that of including Xpaths like you did '(//a[contains(@title,"Series")])[1]' versus the copy-and-paste '//*[@id="panel_STATS_Series_Ext"]/div[1]/h4/a'?

Comment: 1. `presence_of_element_located(`) will wait until the element is located in the HTML. If your connection is faster then the element will load faster or else it will wait till 20 seconds (as we have mentioned while initializing WebDriverWait. 2. Yes, it is a good practice as I am directly targetting the element instead of navigating like '//*[@id="panel_STATS_Series_Ext"]/div[1]/h4/a''.(It's better not to use absolute `XPath` in your code because it may not work in future)

Comment: Great. That helps a lot.